# Problems importing an calendar event into iCal

Tags: ical, import

I'm trying to import a calendar event from an ics file into iCal/Calendar:

**Event details**

1. SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001 1 Lecture(1829)
2. Start date and time: 30/08/2012 and 3.00 PM
3. End date: 12/12/2012 and 3.50 PM
4. MO,WE,FR only these days need to set in the date range(doesn't need to set all day).

**ics file**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//bashmoblie v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120830T150000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121212T155000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
     UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
     CREATED:20091130T213238Z
SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001  1 Lecture(1829)
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
     EQUENCE:0
     STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Class: ACCT 1001  1 Lecture(1829)
LOCATION:Title:  Introduction to Accounting(Lecture)
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Problem**

The problem with this is doesn't correctly import the end time (gets set to 3PM in iCal). How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you trying to import these events into iCal and get an error?

Comment: Am trying to add event to calendar. But the time format is wrong. it doesn't show the correct end time(in this case its 3.50 PM is correct but now it shows 3 PM)

Comment: This doen't work correctly fo me RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121212T155000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no end time for the entry so you need to add this into the file.

```
DTEND:20120830T155000
```

The [ICS specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) also states

> the "UNTIL" recurrence rule parameter MUST be used to specify the
>           last valid onset of this observance (i.e., the UNTIL date-time
>           will be equal to the last instance generated by the recurrence
>           pattern). It MUST be specified in UTC time.

so your RRULE line should read:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121212T150000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR
```